# formGroup expects a FormGroup instance

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have an Angular 2 RC4 basic form example on Plunkr that appears to throw the following error (In Chrome DEV console)

Here's the plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/GtPDxw?p=preview

Error:

```
browser_adapter.ts:82 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in ./App class App - inline template:1:7
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
           Example: <form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">

ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
           Example: <form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">

    at new BaseException (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/forms@0.2.0/src/facade/exceptions.js:27:23)
    at FormGroupDirective._checkFormPresent (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/forms@0.2.0/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.js:110:19)
    at FormGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/forms@0.2.0/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.js:39:14)
    at DebugAppView._View_App0.detectChangesInter
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code

- `<div [formGroup]="form">` outside of a `<form>` tag
- `<form [formGroup]="form">` but the name of the property containing the `FormGroup` is `loginForm` therefore it should be `<form [formGroup]="loginForm">`
- `[formControlName]="dob"` which passes the value of the property `dob` which doesn't exist. What you need is to pass the string `dob` like `[formControlName]="'dob'"` or simpler `formControlName="dob"`

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tyy54M?p=preview)

Comment: Also this might happens when you haven't create form in .ts file.

Comment: or if you are creating dynamically

Comment: Or the name is case sensitive in HTML or in ts

Comment: This might happens if ngOnInit() has 'await' , so in this case you have to define the form group in the constructor

Answer (score 82):

I was facing this issue and fixed by putting a check in form attribute. This issue can happen when the FormGroup is not initialized.

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" *ngIf="loginForm">
OR
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" *ngIf="this.loginForm">
```

This will not render the form until it is initialized.

Comment: Just remove this if someone copying it. I had to ues ngOnInit() method to avoid this

Comment: @amrography I couldn't get you. can you please explain bit more. Thanks

Comment: just edit this part `*ngIf="this.loginForm"` to be `*ngIf="loginForm"`

Comment: This was just what I needed as well. :)

Answer (score 11):

I was using reactive forms and ran into similar problems. What helped me was to make sure that I set up a corresponding `FormGroup` in the class. 
Something like this:

```
myFormGroup: FormGroup = this.builder.group({
    dob: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I had a the same error and solved it after moving initialization of `formBuilder` from `ngOnInit` to constructor.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error and I solvit removing the async await pattern from it:
**orginal code**

```js
async ngOnInit()
{
  this.id = await this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

**working code**

```js
ngOnInit()
{
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

I think might be related to @johannesMatevosyan answer just above.
I really don't know why, but is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error when I had specified [fromGroupName](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupName) instead of [formArrayName](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName).

Make sure you correctly specify if it is a form array or form group.

`<div formGroupName="formInfo"/>`

`<div formArrayName="formInfo"/>`

Answer (score 1):

***Problem Code:***

In your HTML file:

```
<div [formGroup]="myFormm">
    <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>
```

In your TS file:

```
public myForm!: FormGroup;
public myFormm!: any;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.myFormm = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: ['',Validators.required]
    });
}
```

***Solution Code:***

> Please Make sure that Your form name in HTML and in TS file both are
> same or not!!

In your HTML file:

```
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>
```

In your TS file:

```
public myForm!: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: ['',Validators.required]
    });
}
```