# Is it possible to have an Angular 2 formGroup without a form tag?

Tags: angular, forms, tags, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm looking to [Angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html), and there is no way to find what is the best practice about how to use **formGroup**.

> **Is it mandatory to enclose a `formGroup` with a form tag ?**

I've looked to this stack overflow question:

**[formGroup expects a FormGroup instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444778/formgroup-expects-a-formgroup-instance)**

I've created this component template:

```
<div [formGroup]="infoIdentityForm">
  <div class="info-identity_title" *ngIf="showTitle">
    <div class="group-title">Titre</div>
    <div class="group-radio">
      <span *ngFor="let choice of enumTitleValue">
        <label>{{choice}}</label>
        <input type="radio" formControlName="title" name="title" [id]="choice"/>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="info-identity_firstname">
    <div class="group-title">Prénom</div>
    <div class="group-input">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" maxlength="25">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="info-identity_lastname">
    <div class="group-title">Nom</div>
    <div class="group-input">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lastName" maxlength="25">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to **avoid the use of nested form tags**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `formGroupName` directive

> This directive can only be used with a parent FormGroupDirective
>   (selector: [formGroup]).
>
> It accepts the string name of the nested FormGroup you want to link,
>   and will look for a FormGroup registered with that name in the parent
>   FormGroup instance you passed into FormGroupDirective.
>
> Nested form groups can come in handy when you want to validate a
>   sub-group of a form separately from the rest or when you'd like to
>   group the values of certain controls into their own nested object.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroupName-directive.html

```
<div formGroupName="infoIdentityForm">
</div>
```

Which, per the documentation, needs to be in a `<form [formGroup]="formProperty">` at some point to be legally defined and avoid multiple `<form>` tags being used.

If you have a child component you still need the `[formGroup]` but it can be not in a `<form>` tag. If you want to use it all in one big form then you'll need to input your FormGroup from the parent and set it like:

```html
<td [formGroup]="parentGroup">
  <input type="text" formControlName="myControl"
</td>
```

```js
@Input() parentGroup: FormGroup;
```