# Angular2 http observables - how to work with get of undefined?

Tags: angular2-forms, angular2-services

I tried to use service for validation am getting errors as listed below
1:**ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.**

Example:

```
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">    
  <input formControlName="firstName">    
</div>
```

In your class:

```
this.myGroup = new FormGroup({    
   firstName: new FormControl()    
});
```

2.

```
ng:///AppModule/HeroFormReactiveComponent.ngfactory.js:95 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at FormGroupDirective.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (vendor.bundle.js:64292)
    at FormControlName.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (vendor.bundle.js:64881)
    at FormControlName.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (vendor.bundle.js:64799)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (vendor.bundle.js:55512)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor.bundle.js:57011)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (vendor.bundle.js:56950)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (vendor.bundle.js:57811)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (vendor.bundle.js:57752)
    at Object.View_HeroFormReactiveComponent_0._co [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/HeroFormReactiveComponent.ngfactory.js:218)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (vendor.bundle.js:57737)
```

I think I should use observable/ call back function so that we can call functions() after getting the data from service. But I am not sure how to do this... Thanks in advance

TS:

```
export class HeroFormReactiveComponent implements OnInit {
  loginDetailsArray: any;
  detailsArray: any[];
  minLength: any;
  maxLength: any;
  pattern: any;
  // customerDetail: any[];


  hero = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    email: ''
  };
  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService, private http: Http) {}


  heroForm: FormGroup;


  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.loginDetailsArray = new Object();
    this.detailsArray = new Array();
    this.loadLoginDetails();



  }


  functions() {

    console.log("print");
    console.log(this.loginDetailsArray);

    var minLength = this.loginDetailsArray.rules.username.minlength;
    var maxLength = this.loginDetailsArray.rules.username.maxlength;
    var pattern = this.loginDetailsArray.rules.username.pattern;


    this.heroForm = new FormGroup({

      'username': new FormControl(this.hero.username, [
        Validators.minLength(this.minLength),
        Validators.maxLength(this.maxLength),
        //  Validators.pattern(pattern),
      ]),
      'password': new FormControl(this.hero.password, [
        Validators.minLength(2),
        Validators.maxLength(30),
      ]),
    });
  }

  loadLoginDetails() {

    this.customerService.getLoginDetails().subscribe(res => {

      this.loginDetailsArray = res.json();

      this.functions();

    });
  }




  get username() {
    return this.heroForm.get('username');
  }
  get password() {
    return this.heroForm.get('password');
  }

  save() {

    console.log('Saved: ' + JSON.stringify(this.heroForm.value));


    this.detailsArray.push(this.heroForm.value);


  }
}
```

SERVICE:

```
    @Injectable()
export class CustomerService{

    constructor(private http:Http){}


    getLoginDetails(){

        console.log("getLoginDetails")
        //return this.http.get(assets/login.json).map((response: Response) => response.json());
        return this.http.get('assets/login.json').map((response: Response) => response);

    }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">

    <h1>Login</h1>

    <form (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="heroForm" #formDir="ngForm">


        <div [hidden]="formDir.submitted">

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="username">username</label>
                <input id="username" class="form-control" formControlName="username">

                <div *ngIf="username.invalid && (username.dirty || username.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">

                    <div *ngIf="username.errors.required">
                        required
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="username.errors.minlength">
                        Please enter a valid email that does not exceed the character limit
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="username.errors.maxlength">
                        Please enter a valid email that does not exceed the character limit
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="username.errors.pattern">
                        Please enter a valid email address
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input id="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" required>

                <div *ngIf="password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">

                    <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">
                        required
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">
                        Please enter a password with minimum characters
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="password.errors.maxlength">
                        Please enter a password that does not exceed 30 characters
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>



            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="heroForm.invalid">Submit</button>
            <!--<td colspan="2">
            <div class="alert alert-danger col-md-12" role="alert" *ngIf="!flag">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{errormsg}}
            </div>
          </td>-->


        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the working version of your requirement.

```
<h1>Login</h1>

<form (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="heroForm" >


    <div >

        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="username">username</label>
            <input #username id="username" class="form-control" formControlName="username">

            <div *ngIf="heroForm.get('username').invalid && (heroForm.get('username').dirty || heroForm.get('username').touched)" class="alert alert-danger">


                <div *ngIf="heroForm.get('username').hasError('minlength')">
                    Please enter a valid email that does not exceed the character limit
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="heroForm.get('username').hasError('maxlength')">
                    Please enter a valid email that does not exceed the character limit
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input #password id="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" required>

            <div *ngIf="heroForm.get('password').invalid && (heroForm.get('password').dirty || heroForm.get('password').touched)" class="alert alert-danger">

                <div *ngIf="heroForm.get('password').hasError('required') && heroForm.get('password').touched"
               class="alert alert-danger"> Password is required.</div>
                <div *ngIf="heroForm.get('password').hasError('minlength')">
                    Please enter a password with minimum characters
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="heroForm.get('password').hasError('maxlength')">
                    Please enter a password that does not exceed 30 characters
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>



        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="heroForm.invalid">Submit</button>
        <!--<td colspan="2">
        <div class="alert alert-danger col-md-12" role="alert" *ngIf="!flag">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{errormsg}}
        </div>
      </td>-->


    </div>
</form>
```

Component.ts

```
 export class SampleComponent OnInit { 

     public  loginDetailsArray: any= [];
     public detailsArray: any= [];
     public minLength: any;
    public   maxLength: any;
       hero = {
       username: '',
       password: '',
        email: ''
      };


      constructor( private dataTableService: DataTableService,private fb: 
    FormBuilder    ) {

    this.dataTableService = dataTableService;
        this.heroForm = new FormGroup({

      'username': new FormControl(this.hero.username),
      'password': new FormControl(this.hero.password, [
        Validators.minLength(2),
        Validators.maxLength(30),
      ]),
    });

  }
                heroForm: FormGroup;
                  public ngOnInit(): void {


            this. loadLoginDetails();


           }

      loadLoginDetails() {

    this.dataTableService.getLoginDetails().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.loginDetailsArray = res;

        this. minLength=this.loginDetailsArray.minlength;
        this.maxLength=this.loginDetailsArray.maxLength;
     console.log("minLength",this.minLength);
     this.heroForm.controls["username"].setValidators([
        Validators.minLength(this.minLength),
        Validators.maxLength(this.maxLength)
        //  Validators.pattern(pattern),
      ]);
      console.log(this.heroForm);



      });
  }
        get username() {
        return this.heroForm.get('username');
          }
       get password() {
        return this.heroForm.get('password');
      }
       save() {

        console.log('Saved: ' + JSON.stringify(this.heroForm.value));


        this.detailsArray.push(this.heroForm.value);


      }


    }
```

service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class DataTableService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

  getLoginDetails(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('./datatable/data/sample.json').map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: am still getting the same error. i get a new error too saying res.json is not a function along with previous two errors mentioned above

Comment: loadLoginDetails() {

        this.customerService.getLoginDetails().subscribe(res => {

      this.loginDetailsArray = res;//remove res.json

      this.functions();

    });
  }

Comment: the two errors i mentioned above are still coming.
1. cannot read property get of undefined
2. formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

Comment: check whether the this.loginDetailsArray  has any value or not.

Comment: For the form group issue please look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444778/formgroup-expects-a-formgroup-instance

Comment: checked it before. everything is clear in mine. the problem is am getting the value of login details array, but not able to get it inside ngOnInit

Comment: declare your array outside ngOnit public loginDetailsArray : Array<any> = [];

Comment: declare your array outside ngOnit public loginDetailsArray : Array<any> = []; also the array manipulations should do inside the subscribe function itself instead of doing in ngOnInit.                                                                                     
         var minLength = this.loginDetailsArray.rules.username.minlength;  move this code to loadLoginDetails() {}

Comment: yes. tried that. i will be calling that function inside ngOnInit. when i call loadlogindetails() inside ngOnInit and try to get the value of minLength it is showing undefined.

Comment: thanks a lot @anisha. really, it works perfect. i was stuck on this for more than 2 days. thanks again. i just have another requirement (i.e) the required should be added only if the data from backend is required = true. could u help on this.

Comment: Add this in your subscribe function  if required =true then this.formGroup.controls["username"].setValidators(Validators.required);