# Angular select dropdown

Tags: angular

The problem i have is when i trying to put list data in to the select dropdown

I tryed a solution from here [formGroup expects a FormGroup instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444778/formgroup-expects-a-formgroup-instance)
but no luck

My component looks like this:

```
 export class LandingPageComponent {
  submitted = false;
  oppoSuits: any = ['Men', 'Women', 'Boys', 'Inspiration']

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) { }

  oppoSuitsForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required]]
  })

  changeSuit(e) {
    this.oppoSuitsForm.get('name').setValue(e.target.value, {
      onlySelf: true
    })
  }


  public handleError = (controlName: string, errorName: string) => {
    return this.oppoSuitsForm.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.oppoSuitsForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(""),

    });
  };
  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.oppoSuitsForm.value))
  }
}
```

and html file:

```
<form [formGroup]="oppoSuitsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <select formControlName="name" (change)="changeSuit($event)">
          <option value="">Choose oppo suit</option>
          <option *ngFor="let suit of oppoSuits">{{suit}}</option>
        </select>
          <div class="error-block" *ngIf="submitted && handleError('name', 'required')">
            You must provide a value!
          </div>

        <button>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

in console i get this:
Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance

and:

Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: try `<form [formGroup]="oppoSuitsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" *ngIf="oppoSuitsForm">` Forms are actually asynchrnous

Comment: If i trying with *ngIf="" form is disappearing

Comment: Yaah, didn't look to close at the code. I see now that you have further issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your form group twice. You just need to instantiate it once, and I suggest to do that inside the constructor.

```js
@Component({...})
export class Component {
  oppoSuitsForm: FormGroup;

  constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.oppoSuitsForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
}
```

This should solve both of your errors.

Comment: like this?

```submitted = false;
  oppoSuits: any = ['Men', 'Women', 'Boys', 'Inspiration']
  oppoSuitsForm: FormGroup;

  constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.oppoSuitsForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
```
still same errors

Comment: Yes, instantiate the form inside the constructor and remove both of the instatiations in your code, when you define the property and in the `ngOnInit` function.

Comment: Ok, removed ngOnInit function.. but still the same errors. Maybe something missing

Comment: This should work, can you create a stackblitz for your issue?

Comment: Its interesting.. in my local files its not working. In stackblitz its working.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsar77

I using version 8

Comment: This is something I can not reproduce anymore. Have you imported the `ReactiveFormsModule`?

Comment: Yes. its imported

Comment: Just installed from scratch again. Works !

Comment: Yay, thats nice, congrats!